# How to use angular-dialog-service with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've found a message box implementation (https://github.com/m-e-conroy/angular-dialog-service) which appears to do exactly what I need, however I can't make it work in a TypeScript environment.

`npm install angular-dialog-service`

I also found the type definitions (although they don't seem to be documented)

`npm install @types/angular-dialog-service`

However when I try to import the types I get

`import * as dlgSvc from 'angular-dialog-service'`

*File 'XXX/node_modules/@types/angular-dialog-service/index.d.ts' is not a module.ts(2306)*

**From @types/angular-dialog-service/index.d.ts**

```
/// <reference types="angular"/>
/// <reference types="angular-ui-bootstrap"/>

declare namespace angular.dialogservice {

  interface IDialogOptions {
  ...
```

Should I be importing this some other way?

Comment: the library is intended to be used with AngularJS, not Angular (as stated in the 'About' section on Github)

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to Angular and didn't realise there was a difference

Comment: AngularJS was the version 1 of the framework. It was renamed Angular starting with version 2 as the framework has been rewritten. it makes libraries not compatibles between these versions.